# How do you traverse multiple SObjects in a Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email, reporting, custom-object, email-template

I am having trouble creating an email template that requires the following field path: `Contact`-->`Opportunity`-->`Account`-->`Factor Data` (custom object on account).

We are trying to put together a commission report for our brokers. The brokers (contacts) are linked to the opportunities. However, the fees earned, purchases, etc. that the opportunity incurs for any given month is found on Factor Data (on the accounts page).

I have little to no experience with coding or Salesforce language. I'm just trying to find out if this is even possible.

Would anyone know a workaround given the following Visualforce template?

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Broker Report" recipientType="Contact"   relatedToType="Opportunity">
    <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
        <html>
            <body>
                <STYLE type="text/css">
                    TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial; background: #CCCCCC;
                    border-width: 1; text-align: center}
                    TD {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana}
                    TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
                    TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
                </STYLE>
                <font face = "arial" size="2">
                    <p>Dear , </p>
                    <p>Below is a detail of your commission report for this month. </p>
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr >
                            <th>Client</th>
                            <th>Purchases</th>
                            <th>Collections</th>
                            <th>Fees Earned</th>
                        </tr>
                        <apex:repeat var="ox" value = "{!relatedTo.Opportunity}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{!ox.Account}</td>
                            <td>{!ox.Purchase_MTD__c}</td>
                            <td>{!ox.Collections__c}</td>
                            <td>{!ox.Earned_Fees__c}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </table>
                    <p />
                </font>
            </body>
        </html>
    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference it, and you don't need to use the `<apex:repeat>` tag. Let's assume, for example, that your relationship from `Account` to `Factor Data` has an API Name of `Factor_Data__c`. The following table shows you how you would reference the object and pull fields from it.

```
SObject        Lookup Field      Relationship Name
Contact        OpportunityId     Opportunity
Opportunity    AccountId         Account
Account        Factor_Data__c    Factor_Data__r
```

So, to reference fields on the related `Factor Data` object, you would use:

```
{!relatedTo.Opportunity.Account.Factor_Data__r.Some_Field__c}
```

Comment: Thank you @AdrianLarson. I appreciate the quick response. I'll test that out.

Comment: Would it be the same scenario if multiple opportunities were tied to the single contact, or would the apex:repeat tag come back into play with the custom object references beneath it?

Comment: That's not how lookup relationships work. The child object is the *many* in the many-to-one relationship, so you could have multiple `Contacts` per `Opportunity`, but not the other way around.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I've encountered that problem in the past. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Hey Adrian, I may have mis-phrased my question. Is it possible to pull all opportunities that the contact is connected to via contact roles? i.e. If a single broker was the 'referral source' on multiple opportunities, could I pull info from each separate opportunity into the email, or would that still violate the many-to-one relationship? Trying to see if the broker being in the contact roles makes a difference. Thanks again.

Comment: You'd likely need to query for them using `Apex`. Sounds like a great new question! Make sure you include as much detail as you can around what you've tried so far and the research you've done. Linking to documentation on the related objects especially will help make sure your question is well received.